# How restrictive is the markov assumption?

Tags: markov-process

Forgive me if this is a basic question.

The markov assumption is generally taken to be restrictive in the texts that I've read.

But intuitively it seems to me that we can turn any dynamic process into a markov process, simply by adding new variables at every time $t$ that record the "non-markov nature" of the relationships between time steps, so that we end up with a markov process in the end.

Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let ${(X_n)}_{n \geq 0}$ be a stochastic process. It is not Markov in general. Define the random variables $Y_n = (X_0, X_1, \ldots, X_n)$. Then ${(Y_n)}_{n \geq 0}$ is a Markov process. Now, note that ${(X_n)}_{n \geq 0}$ and ${(Y_n)}_{n \geq 0}$ generate the same filtration. Thus, we can say that the filtration of any stochastic process is the filtration of a Markov process. I hope this illuminates your idea. I don't see what else can be said.

Comment: It is not clear to me how this explains whether having Markov property (the current state dending solely on the previous state) is a strong assumption or not.